# phpmyadmin - getting info for FK on delete and on update actions

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have to work with an existing DB and right now I have to add a few new tables with foreign keys. I want to see from already made tables how the properties for `on delete` and `on update` events are set because I know they use the same setting for all FK in the DB. So is there any way to see how those two exact options are set in preexisting tables with FK?

Thanks

Leron

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE TableName` will show you the whole script for a table, including FK constarints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` table from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/referential-constraints-table.html):

```
SELECT rc.*
FROM information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc ;
```